# Print a message if an object appears on webcam for more than 5 seconds - Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have the below code that considers a webcam video to detect whether a dog or cat is in the frame. If a cat is in the frame **for more than 5 seconds**, I need to print "Cat is in the frame for more than 5 seconds." How do I achieve this using the below code using Opencv PYTHON?

```
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS,
                                                                    use_display_name=True)
import numpy as np

while True:
    # Read frame from camera
    ret, image_np = cap.read()

    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)

    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
          (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
          detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.30,
          agnostic_mode=False)
    
    # Display output
    cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: We don't know what the classes are assigned to for the output softmax layer.  Please include this in your post.

Comment: dog is 1. Cat is 2

Comment: Is 0 background?

Comment: There is no 0 here. Its just either 1 or 2. My  category index is:
{1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'dog'}, 2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'cat'}}

Comment: So what is `category_index` then?  This is not defined in your code.

Comment: my category is just: label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS,
                                                                    use_display_name=True)

I added it to the code now

Comment: I guess the question is about printing some letters over image, and deleting them after timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model for cat detection is working well with good accuracy you can use time.time() to calculate the required time.

```
start_time = time.time()
"while condt for cat prediction is true" 
   
if (time.time() - start_time) >5:
    print("Cat is in the frame for more than 5 seconds")
```

Sorry for the incomplete code. There are a lot of details missing such as category_index, etc.

Hope this helps. The gist being use start_time = time.time() at the time when ur model gives final output for a cat in the frame while the webcam is reading the data and then subtract it with  time.time() to check.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a multi object tracker (MOT) to assign a tracking ID to each detected object. Consider looking at the [SORT algorithm by Alex Bewley](https://github.com/abewley/sort). It's easy to implement and works well. Basically you feed the algorithm the detections for each frame, and it returns a tracking ID. Since each item tracked gets a unique ID you can track that over time.

See the example on the github page. For your project, you would create the tracking object outside of your `cap.read()` loop:

```
mot_tracker = Sort()
```

Then after each inference, feed the algorithm your detections and get unique IDs for each tracked object that you can measure against time or number of frames:

```
track_bbs_ids = mot_tracker.update(detections)
```

Note that the detections format is a np array of bboxes and scores in format `[[x1,y1,x2,y2,score],[x1,y1,x2,y2,score],...]`